# HAML indentation while processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to generate the following code with HAML within a `.each` loop. Depending on the true/false condition within the loop, it should either create a new `div1` with a `div2` or append `div2` within the previous `div1`. This is a simplification of the logic:

```
Desired output:

if true, append `div2` within `div1`, 

    <div class="div1">    #added by true condition
      div1 text
      <div class="div2">  #added by true condition
        div2 text
      </div>
      <div class="div2">  #added by false condition
        div2 text
      </div>
      <div class="div2">  #added by false condition
        div2 text
      </div>
    </div>

else, create a new `div1` and add `div2` within it

    <div class="div1">    #added by true condition
      div1 text
      <div class="div2">  #added by true condition
        div2 text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div1">    #new div1, added by true condition
      div1 text
      <div class="div2">  #added by true condition
        div2 text
      </div>
    </div>
```

Effectively, I'm trying to do this

```
  //within a loop logic
    - if condition == true
      .div1
        div1 text
    -# in all conditions
        .div2
          div2 text
```

This is my HAML logic, I was using `tab_up` but I don't think that's the correct HAML method:

```
  //within a loop logic
    - if condition == true
      .div1
        div1 text
    - tab_up(2)  #trying to indent the HAML, not just the HTML output
    .div2
       div2 text
```

Comment: What do you mean by “generated programmatically”? In order for `div2` to be inside `div1` it needs to be more indented in the Haml source than `div1`. `tab_up` just controls the output appearance, it doesn’t effect the structure. You need to provide an example of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: The question isn't clear. The solution you ruled out is obviously the right one.

Comment: Thanks matt & depa, I've tried to clear this up some more.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do things like this in Haml is to organise your data before tying to convert it to HTML. The methods of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) can help here.

The way you’ve described the problem, splitting your enumerable with [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) looks like the most direct solution – you want to open a new `div1` before every item where the condition is true (here I’m assuming that the condition depends on the item). Possibly something like this:

```haml
- items.slice_before {|item| determine_condition(item) }.each do |div1_block|
  .div1
    div1 text
    - div1_block.each do |item|
      .div2
        div2 text
```

Depending on what you’re actually trying to do, there may be a better way to organise your data – the way it is described here suggests you are looking at it at a lower level than needed because you are already thinking in terms of iterating and creating the HTML as you go.

The basic idea would be to get an array (or `Enumerator`) of arrays, with each inner array representing the contents of a `div1`. The Haml then falls out pretty easily. [`chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk), [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) are some `Enumerable` methods that might be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Unfortunately, due to other requirements, the models can't be grouped before hand. It is sequenced in the correct order though.